# Writing to a file errors and permission errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    try:
        enterName = input("Enter the name of the file:") + ".txt"

    latinFile = open(enterName,"r")
    read = latinFile.readlines()
    for lines in read:  
        store.append(lines.strip()) 
    checkSquare (store) 
    print ("File:")
    for content in store:
        print (content)

    saveData(store)
```

I think the problem is with the code for saving the file contents.
The aim is for the code to open the file,read the contents and it checks to see if the format of the file is correct etc and then if that is all true and it works, it will save the file again (saveData) but it will rename the file so that it says in the directory that it has been validated.

However, the code isn't working ( the os.rename part) and also I keep getting a permissionerror and I don't know how to fix it.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\Desktop\python\idkll.py", line 44,in <module>
    saveData(store)
  File "C:\Users\---\Desktop\python\idkll.py", line 18, in saveData
    os.rename (fileName,"VALIDATED" + fileName)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'OPENEDve.txt'
```

Comment: Did you try running python as an administrator? It's likely that you don't have write permission on the directory that the file is in.

Comment: You have indentation errors on your `except` stuff, and a typo: `storee`

Comment: could you post the exact error message you get

Comment: Yes, I do.  PM 2Ring is correct: you didn't close your file before renaming it, so it is your process that is accessing it.  You could use `file.close()` after your `for` loop, but it would be better to put all of that into a [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt) block.  You should also consider using a different name for your open file because `file` (in Python2) conflicts with the built-in type. You are using Python3, so that shouldn't effect you; but it's good to be compatible.

Comment: @zondo ok, going to try put it into a with statement now, without using it I tested the code and it said "TypeError: illegal type for path parameter". Is that os.rename code I'm using bad? The task requires me to rename the file so that it says VALIDATED beforehand. Are there any other methods?

Comment: You appear to be using `os.rename()` correctly.  I tested your code, and it worked fine for me.  I did a quick search for that error, however, and it was suggested to print the path before trying to rename, and see what it prints.  I haven't been able to recreate the error message, though, so I don't know what the problem might be.  Based on below answers, I would guess that I can't recreate it because I'm on linux, but you could try to print it, and see what it comes up with.

Comment: @zondo I fixed it. In os.rename(saveFile,"OPENED" + enterName) I need to use enterName instead of saveFile at the start and now it works.

Comment: That's great.  I was even looking for that, and I didn't notice ;)  I guess I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Just change `file.write(letters)` to `file.write(letters + os.linesep)`.  (I use `os.linesep` because that is where Python stores what the most common new line character is).  You could also just remove the `.strip()` when you say `store.append(lines.strip())` in your `while` loop.  Calling `.strip()` will remove the new line that was already there, so if you want the new line, just don't strip it.

Comment: @zondo hi, sorry to tag you again but you always got help me :). I misread the task and actually I needed to make a NEW file instead of renaming it and in mine I am renaming ;( . How do I do that? I know how to rename but not how to make a new file.

Comment: For that, you can use the shutil module: `shutil.copy(enterName, "OPENED" + enterName)`

Comment: @zondo interesting! going to read up on this module then, any other methods which also do this? Just for learning for future

Comment: @zondo also with shutil it also means I can't use os.linesep so the way it is copied to the new file is wrong. will try to find a shutil version.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is you are trying to do, but if it is just that you don't want to save to `enterName` at all, and you just want to save to `"OPENED" + enterName`, change that in your `open(..., 'w')` on the first line in `saveData()`.  If you want to write to both, put `saveFile2 = open("OPENED" + enterName, 'w')` below `saveFile = open(...)`, and then in your `for` loop, add `saveFile2.write(character + os.linesep)`.  Also, put `saveFile2.close()` below `saveFile.close()`

Comment: @zondo ok that first part made sense with the 'OPENED' + enterName. I was just making everything very confusing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close your files as soon as you finish reading from them or writing to them. And you should close the file before attempting to rename it. You can either use the file's `.close()` method, or use a `with` statement so that files get closed automatically.

Incidentally, your `saveData()` function should probably not prompt the user for the filename: just pass it the name you already have in `enterName`. Also, prepending `"VALIDATED"` to the filename is not a good strategy. It's ok if you're just using relative filenames in the current directory, but it will make a mess of a proper file path.

---

In response to the update:

`saveFile` does *not* contain a file name string, it's a Python object representing your open file (also known as a file handle). The name of that file is the string in `enterName`. So you need to do something like

```
os.rename(enterName, enterName + "VALIDATED")
```

Comment: that what i suspected too, but i created a MCVE without closing my file and it still got renamed

Comment: @danidee: I'm _guessing_ it's a Windows quirk (I only run Linux). FWIW, I suspect that once this problem is fixed the OP will discover further logic bugs in their code.

Comment: oooh my bad. my MCVE wasn't an MCVE because i'm also running linux

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks + also the task says I need to make it so that the file says validated once it has run through all the other checks and then it saves the file.

Comment: @JohnPal: So is the rename working now that you close the files properly?

Comment: @PM2Ring no it's not. It gives the error:  "TypeError: illegal type for path parameter". Is it because I am using variables instead of a string?

Comment: @JohnPal: Ok. But it looks like we've fixed the permission problem. It's perfectly fine to use a variable for the new file name, but the variable **must** be a string, and it must be a legal file path. If the new filename is in a variable called `newfilename` try `print(repr(newfilename), type(newfilename))` before the `rename` call. That will show us what `newfilename` actually contains and what type of object it is.

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry I didn't really understand what you meant by the newfilename part. I have a hard time understanding some english due to language barrier as it doesn't really make sense when I transalte it in my head.. sorry for being I guess stupid?  I understand that you want me to do print(repr(saveFile),type(saveFile)) ?  I also updated code in main body to what I changed everything to. sorry again for being stupid

Comment: @JohnPal: No. `saveFile` does _not_ contain a file name string, it's a Python object representing your open file. The name of that file is the string in `enterName`. So you need to do something like `os.rename(enterName, enterName + "VALIDATED")`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Wow...The problem was so stupid! All I had to do was read it properly and I understand. Thanks very much and sorry for wasting your time !

Comment: @JohnPal: Well, we got there in the end. FWIW, probably _every_ programmer gets file names and file handles mixed up when they first start. :) BTW, you now have enough rep to up-vote :wink:

Answer (score 0):

Just swap `os.rename (fileName,"VALIDATED" + fileName)` and `file.close()` lines inside saveData() function.
You should close the file prior to trying to rename it. The error is because your program is actually using the file it is trying to rename.